# Acceleo service

Tags: java, service, acceleo

I have to wrap a java function inside an Acceleo File that returns my own complex type ...

[query public methodeTest(arg0 : Package, arg1 : Class, arg2 : Property) : MyOwnComplexeType
    = invoke('org.eclipse.acceleo.module.sample.services.UML2Services', 'methodeTest(org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Package, org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Class, org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Property)', Sequence{arg0, arg1, arg2}) /]

But it doesn't work when i want to acced ta o property in my template !!!

Can U Help me !

Comment: Please, describe better what your code is supposed to do and how do you access it. Also, consider using code tags so that your source code is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleo services can only return primitive types (String, Boolean, Integer, etc...), element of the currently used meta-model (in your case UML elements) or collections of those elements.

Regards,

Stephane Begaudeau